# Knuth's Algorithm X for exact cover with restricted block sizes

Tags: algorithm, knuth

The famous algorithm for [exact cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover) is given by Donald Knuth called Knuth's Algorithm X.

```
Input: List of subsets of a Universal sets
Output: All the possible disjoint subset whose union is Universal set
```

Suppose the input is `{ab, ac, cd, c, d, a, b}`. Is it possible to make the Knuth's Algorithm X such that it will give output according to some predefined block size. For example if `{2, 2}` is the block size set, it will give output: `{ab, cd}`, if `{2,1,1}` is the block size set, it will give output: `{ab, c, d}`, `{ac, b, d}` and `{cd, b, a}`.

Comment: I think that the best is to create your own algorithm, you generate all set that respect the predefined block size then you delete those whose union is not Universal set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can (optionally) start with removing all subsets from your input list that does not have size in set of block sizes.

The original Knuth's Algorithm X can be altered with the set of block sizes (for example {2, 1, 1}) as a restriction using extensions in **bold** as follows:

1. If `A` is empty **and set of block sizes is empty**, the problem is solved; terminate successfully.
2. Otherwise choose a column, `c` (deterministically).
3. Choose a row, `r`, such that `A[r, c] = 1` and **number of 1s in row `r` is in the set of block sizes** (nondeterministically).
4. Include `r` in the partial solution
5. **Remove number of 1s in row `r` from set of block sizes**
6. For each `j` such that `A[r, j] = 1`,
      Delete column `j` from matrix `A`;
      For each `i` such that `A[i, j] = 1`,
          Delete row `i` from matrix `A`.
7. Repeat this algorithm recursively on the reduced matrix `A` and **reduced set of block sizes**.

Comment: Thanks I did not think about it. The problem I was facing for block sizes {2,1,1} is it gives all the solution with sizes {2,1,1} but also it gives solution of block sizes {2,2},{1,1,1,1}. I will check this. Hope it will work. Thank you for this solution. I was thinking about the solution using Knuth X but failed. I will check Knuth X according to your way.